# Confidence Interval for a proportion with weighted sampling

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, statistical-significance, confidence-interval, proportion

I have some binary outcome data - let's imagine it's inputs to some system, and based on the input, the system can return either "good" or "bad". Different inputs occur with different frequencies; input 1 could happen 5 times, while input 2 could happen 700 times. Some example data is below:

| input ID | rating | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | good | 5 |
| 2 | good | 700 |
| 3 | bad | 48 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 1M | good | 6 |

I want to compute a confidence interval that shows that the proportion of times the system returns "good" is >= .99. I want to do this by randomly sampling input IDs, but that's complicated by the weights; if there weren't weights to the input IDs, then I could just use a confidence interval for a proportion or a beta distribution. But given the weights, I don't think I can do that - for example, if I sampled input ID 2 and evaluated it first, then I would have 700 successes and 0 failures to start, which is already significant.

I can think of two potential solutions:

1. Dis-aggregate the data so that we have one line for each count of each ID, and then sample without replacement from that and do a normal confidence interval on a proportion:

| input ID | rating | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | good | 1 |
| 1 | good | 1 |
| 1 | good | 1 |
| 1 | good | 1 |
| 1 | good | 1 |
| 2 | good | 1 |
| 2 | good | (698 more entries) |
| 2 | good | 1 |
| 3 | bad | 1 |
| 3 | bad | (46 more entries) |
| 3 | bad | 1 |

2. Weighted sample with replacement from the original table (the weighted sampling being done by the `count` variable). This should yield an equivalent sample to the one above, allowing me to use a normal confidence interval for a proportion calculation.

Both of those seem valid to me, but I'm curious if there's a better way to do this (especially one that allows me to use the knowledge of the weights to evaluate less data)?